# k-flats in homogeneous spaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, homogeneous-spaces, geodesics

In a symmetric space of rank $k$ (and I'll take $k > 1$) *every* geodesic is contained in a $k$-flat: a totally geodesic, flat, connected, and closed submanifold of dimension $k$.

**Question.** Are there non-symmetric homogeneous spaces that share this property?

In this [paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s002090050507) the author shows that if we also require that the isometry group act transitively on the set of pairs $(p, \Sigma)$, where $\Sigma$ is a flat and $p$ is a point in it, then the space is symmetric.

My main interest is having many examples, *homogeneous or not*, of compact
Riemannian manifolds for which every geodesic is contained in a totally geodesic, flat torus of dimension $k > 1$.

Comment: I think the product of two rank 1 spaces will have the property (if the geodesics in the factors are closed subsets), but need not be symmetric.

Comment: If you assume, in addition that your manifold has nonpositive curvature, then the celebrated **rank rigidity theorem** (Ballmann-Brin-Eberlein, Burns-Spatzier)  states that the universal cover of your manifold splits isometrically as a product of symmetric spaces and manifolds of negative curvature. I am not sure what happens if the curvature is allowed to be positive.

Comment: The product of two Riemannian manifolds has this property: each geodesic projects to a geodesic or point in each factor, so lies in a product of geodesics. (David Witte Morris is not quite right: the product of symmetric spaces is symmetric.)

Comment: @BenMcKay. Yes, thanks. I can then add the  product of Zoll spheres between themselves and with compact symmetric spaces to the compact symmetric spaces of rank > 1 to my list (I really want tori).

Comment: Perhaps this can be useful: http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2001-129-12/S0002-9939-01-06008-7/S0002-9939-01-06008-7.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the k-flats are compact, then the space must be symmetric
(Molina-Olmos, J. Differential geometry
45 (1997) 575-592; see also Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 129 (2001), 3701-3709).

Homogeneous spaces (non-symmetric and irreducible) with the property that every geodesic is contained in a k-flat ($k\geq 2$) can be constructed as follows 
(due to Ernst Heintze): choose a simple compact Lie group $G$ and a compact 
subgroup $H$ such that $\mathrm{rank} (G)\geq \mathrm{dim} (H) +2$. Then  $G/H$, with the normal hogeneous metric is a desired example (see also  Spatzier-Strake,  Comment. Math. Helv. 65 (1990) 299-317).  Observe that the projection from $G$, with the bi-invariant metric, onto $G/H$, with the normal homogeneous metric, is a Riemannian submersion.}

(The known fact that $G/H$ is irreducible, as a Riemannian manifold, can be found in Olmos-Reggiani-Tamaru, Math.Z. 277 (2014), 611-628).